# Emulator: PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU. on Windows10

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I use Windows 10 and android studio v3.1.2
I want to use AVD in android studio
I download systemImages for API 27 and put it in sdk , systemimages folder
It worked properly and it was not a problem.
and I create a virtual device .
Now, when I start it, the below error occurs in event Log:

Emulator: PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.

What should I do ?[This is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzvCu.png)

Answer (score 6):

Take into account, that the path to emulator had changed, so don't use ...../Android/Sdk/tools/emulator but instead ....../Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator

Comment: How to change this path in visual studio? VS is always trying to use `../tools/..`

Answer (score 4):

Please go to the SDK Manager and then select SDK Tools. Check if the 'Android Emulator', 'Android SDK Tools' and 'Android SDK Platform-Tools' are installed. If not, please install them and see if you are getting the same error.

I was getting the error but then installed these packages. After installation, the emulator was working without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if your enviorment variables are not set up properly.

Please try the following:

If you face the same error, here are the step by step instructions:

1. In Windows search type `Environment` then click `Edit the system environment variables`
2. Click `Environment Variables` in the bottom right
3. Under `User variables for {Insert Username Here}` click `New`
4. Enter `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` for the `Variable name`
5. Enter `C:/Users/<username>/.android` for `Variable value`
6. Click ok, then click ok, then click ok
7. Restart your computer
8. Try again